# How to join an active session running on a Chromcast device

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I have to Users (User A and B) and one Chromecast device (C1).
User B starts a stream on C1.
User A connects to C1

Now User A should be able to control the stream running on C1. But every time I want to start a session the running stream on C1 is shut down and the receiver app is restarting.

Is there a way to join an active session? Or is that a job which has to be done by the web app running on the Chromecast device?

EDIT:
my sender app is a native Android app
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I figured it out by myself: It wasn't such complicated at all

I started the an Application like this

```
  try {
     mSession.startSession(applicationName,applicationArgs);
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
  }
```

But it seems, that the MimeData applicationArgs is not needed at all. By removing the arguments and starting the session like below it works really fine!

```
  try {
     mSession.startSession(applicationName);
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
  }
```

I hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to the TicTacToe application. I think it does exactly that where 2 players can join the same game :

https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-tictactoe

Hope this helps.
JN

Comment: I checked out this before but I couldn't find ANY difference... But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What sort of sender are you using? Is it a native app (i.e. using Android or iOs SDK on a mobile device) or the sender is a chrome app?

Comment: oh sorry, I use a native Andorid App as sender app

Comment: The reason I asked for the type of sender is that the current Chrome APIs do not support multiple concurrent connections. Since you answered you were using an Android SDK, please share  some of your code so we can make some suggestions otherwise it is difficult to see what is going wrong; it would be great if we could see both receiver and sender codes. By the way, why is my question down-voted??

Comment: I cant't to post the code of the receiver app because it isn't developed by me. My sender app isn't very different from the sample app and the tutorial published by google. So I think there hast to be done something "special" Btw. I didn't the downvote your answer :O

Comment: Which tutorial you are referring to? You can turn on logging in SDK and get more info on that; to do so, look for "Enable Logging in the SDK" toward the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

On the receiver, you create a Receiver object and a ChannelHandler.  You use the receiver to generate a ChannelFactory which you then pass to the ChannelHandler.  The ChannelHandler now handles the creation of channels on the receiver.  You will want to add an EventListener to the handler to listen to messages.  Based on those messages you can do various things.

```
receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(YOUR_APP_ID, [YOUR_PROTOCOL], "", 5);
var dashHandler = new cast.receiver.ChannelHandler(YOUR_PROTOCOL);
dashHandler.addChannelFactory(receiver.createChannelFactory(YOUR_PROTOCOL));
dashHandler.addEventListener(cast.receiver.Channel.EventType.MESSAGE, onMessage.bind(this));
receiver.start();

...

onMessage = function (e) {
    var message = e.message;
    switch (message.type) {
       ...
    }
}
```

On the sender, after a session is created you will want to send a check status message to the receiver to see if there are already channels attached.  You can do this via your MessageStream and your receiver needs to respond in such a way that the MessageStream gets its status updated.  You check that status to see if there are channels.  If there are you can start listening to updates for your receiver.  If not you can send a load event to the receiver to start your activity.

```
MediaProtocolCommand cmd = mMessageStream.requestStatus();
cmd.setListener(new MediaProtocolCommand.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(MediaProtocolCommand mPCommand) {
        if (mMessageStream.getState() == 'channelsExist') {
            //Start New Activity
       } else {
            //Join Existing Activity
       }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(MediaProtocolCommand mPCommand) {
    }
});
```

This is kind of a vague response, but it could be more specific if I knew what you were trying to do.  My app is using Google's RAMP protocol to play videos so my MessageStream and all it's messages are already defined.  If you're doing something different, you need to create your own MessageStream.